# AutomationElement.FromPoint gets the wrong element

Tags: c#, windows-10

In windows 10, when I take mouse coordinates found via [Inspect.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) ([Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)) and put them in [AutomationElement.FromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.frompoint(v=vs.110).aspx) I get the wrong element on very specific elements (I usually get the correct element). E.g. the left half of Notepad++'s maximize button returns the minimize button. The left half of the minimize button returns the window's header.

How does Inspect.exe get the correct element? Should I be using a different API?

PS

Given that the second line here evaluates to false:

```
var el = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
bool shouldBeTrue = el.Current.BoundingRectangle.Contains(point);
```

I was able to write a workaround that goes up the element tree (from el to the first element that contains the point) and then down and finds the lowest element that contains the point. But I'd rather have a solution that I doesn't require such a hack.